# Use of pronouns - coppie di pronomi atoni - with negation

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, sentences

> Non hanno dato a voi il libro.

Are the following transformations correct? ->

> Non ci hanno dato il libro.

Or should we say

> Ci non hanno dato il libro.

Then ->

> Non ce l'hanno dato.

Is this also correct? ->

> Non ce lo hanno dato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the transformations are correct because the personal pronoun in the initial sentence is *voi/vi* and not *noi/ci*. The correct transformations are:

> Non vi hanno dato il libro.

> Non ve l'hanno dato.